# How do you manage the user groups that users are assoicated to in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, permissions, user

How do I add/remove users to user groups on Mac OS X 10.5? Like 'bonic_master' for instance.. and out of curiosity how do I create a user group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In System Preferences, under the Account section, Click the plus button.  Select from the Account Type drop down menu that you want a Group.  Give it name and click Create.  Select the group from the list of users on the left hand side and check the users you want to be included in that group.

Remove users and groups that appear in the list by highlighting the item and clicking the Minus button.  You choose if you want to keep the home folder of users.

Comment: hmm, so I go to 'System Preferences' then 'Accounts' and the only '+' button I see seems to allow me to create 4 different types of users (admin, standard, manged by parental controls, sharing only) and groups. So that is how I create a group I guess, thanks for explaining that.

It appears that I did not already have any groups, but I do have the 'boinc_master' group when I install boinc, so I guess this is a hidden group that I have to manage via command line?